# UVa Online judge-3n+1probelm(Wrong answer)

Tags: java

I am pretty sure my program works,because it gives mw the same result as uv-output. But it said my answer is wrong. Some of you might know about this site. I'm still beginner and inexperienced, so I hope to have some help. Perhaps something that I miss about that problem. 
this is the probelm link >>
(http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&category=3&problem=36&mosmsg=Submission+received+with+ID+13417700)
Here's my  code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException  {
        Main myWork=new Main();
        File inputFile=new File("input.txt");
        if(inputFile.exists()){
            Scanner scan=new Scanner(inputFile);
            while(scan.hasNext()){
                int i=scan.nextInt();
                int j=scan.nextInt();
                int count =0;
                for(int x=i; x<=j;++x){ 
                    int y= myWork.doAlgorithem(x);
                    if(count <y)
                        count=y;

                }
                System.out.println(i+" "+j+" "+count);
            }}
        System.exit(0);
    }
    public static int doAlgorithem(int i)
    {
        int count=1;

        while( i != 1){
            if(i % 2 != 0){
                count++;
                i= i*3 +1;
            }
            else 
            {
                count++;
                i /=2;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code and add a description of the problem statement. A link to the problem would also be nice.

Comment: First of all when you complete main , just return 0. do not use System.exit(0).

Comment: @Naruto `return 0` from a `void` method? In any case, that cannot possibly cause a problem in this case

Comment: sorry my mistake. it's java. so don't return but don't use System.exit(0).

Comment: @NiklasB here is the link for the problem >>
(http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&category=3&problem=36&mosmsg=Submission+received+with+ID+13417700)

Comment: I think it might have to do with a corner case. Isn't 1 1 supposed to return 2? Yours returns 1.
"For each pair of input integers i and j you should output i, j, and the maximum cycle length for integers between and including i and j."

Comment: @Yarneo i am not sure that i understand that it have to return 2 in 1 1 case :/ !!

Comment: Well it seems that the cycle length includes both numbers, so even in 1 1 it would seem that they might be looking for the answer 2.

Comment: @Yarneo i tried what you said, but still give me wrong error :(

Comment: Well honestly, I always don't like these online judge things just because they are sometimes filled with very odd and unthinkable corner cases. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: no you shouldn't be :D thank you very much because you tried :) that's enough for me :D @Yarneo

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem with your solution is that you assume that the first integer is always smaller than the second.

Whey you are solving programming problems from / based in contests, you should **never** make any assumptions.

Try your code with these cases, extracted from [here](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/UVa_100).

```
1 10
100 200
201 210
900 1000
1000 900
999999 999990
```

The output should be:

```
1 10 20
100 200 125
201 210 89
900 1000 174
1000 900 174
999999 999990 259
```